# I can't figure out why this regular expression isn't working

Tags: regex

So I'm currently learning about regular expressions, and was trying out the exercises here: https://regex.sketchengine.co.uk/cgi/ex4.cgi

In particular, I've been able to match every line on the left (without matching any lines on the right), except for the following line:

```
mess! He did not let it
```

I know this must be a hideous answer, but here is what I have:

```
^[mbadhi][^n]..[^W]([a-zA-Z'") ]+[.!?][a-zA-Z'") ]+)
```

What I don't understand (besides why it doesn't work), is when I remove the 'n' inside [^n], it matches the sentence (but also a pieces of the right side). I must be missing something pretty fundamental, because my understanding is that ^[mbadhi] should match the first character of any line that starts with one of those letters and then any second letter that isn't the letter 'n'. 'me' from mess should match that, no?

Comment: fyi this works: `(['",()\w\n ]|\.\.\.)+($|[.?!])`

Comment: I'd use `[a-z][….?!][»"'})\]]?\s+[A-Z]`. The problem is that your understanding of `[^n]` is wrong: it matches `l`, `5`, `§`, `%`, etc. - **any char but `n`**.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that was my intention with [^n]. Assuming my understanding of the question was correct (which it was not.. I was supposed to match entire sentences, not just lines), that [^n] was meant to exclude the first row on the right side (second character being an 'n') without affecting any lines on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are trying to solve is kind of lame because there is no way to determine one column from another the way they have it formatted. So, the answer is completely data specific. I don't think you would ever see this in practice.

Either way, this works:

```
(^[amhd].*$|^it.*$|^but w.*$)
```

To answer your question; when you take out the `n` in `[^n]..[^W]` making it `[^]..[^W]` this causes the first `]` to be a part of the `character class` selection, i.e., you are saying; not any of the following caracters `]..[^W`

To state again, removing the `n` causes the second `]` to be the ending `character class` delimiter, not the one immediately after the first `^`.

This is why it stops after the second period on the following lines:

`assumes word senses. Within in the U.S.`A., people often

`always thought so.) Then but W. G.` Grace never had much

Comment: Thank you very much. Very enlightening!

Answer (score 0):

What the exercise wants you to solve, as quoted:

> ... one sentence ends and another begins ...

However your answer seems not doing anything close to it.

Some hints if you want to solve it yourself:

1. A sentence need to end with some "terminating" punctuation, like `. ) ! ? ' "`
2. A sentence begin with end of a previous sentence, follow by space, and follow up capital letter
3. There are exception that abbreviations can be written as one capital letter, followed by full-stop, follow by space.

My solution (obviously not the best) that can solve the exercise is (spoiler alter):

> `^.*(?<![A-Z])[.\?"')!] +[A-Z].*$`

Comment: Ahh, I definitely misunderstood the question. Based on the previous three lessons, I was supposed to match lines, so I proceeded off that assumption.  That said, any reason my attempt wasn't matching that particular line?